# Get proper boot on Grub2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, bootloader

This question is very similar to others one but I haven’t find a precise answer to my problem.

I have one hard drive, with 4 partitions :

- A first system partition with window's bootloader
- A partition with windows 8.1
- A partition with ubuntu 12 and ubuntu bootloader
- And a storage one

I've installed windows first. Using easyBCD I can choose to boot either on windows or ubuntu, everything is working. When I select ubuntu, it goes on grub, with another boot selection, I find this very dirty : **I would like to directly start on grub, how can I do that ?**

I've broke BCD a few time doing dumb things like installing ubuntu's bootloader on the BCD partition ... I'm a noob with IT (by the way please forgive any vocabulary misuse).

Is there a simple way to achieve that ? like saying to my HDD to boot on the grub's partition, will it work ?

Comment: Are you using the new UEFI or old BIOS (or equivalently the CMS/Legacy mode of UEFI, that works like the old BIOS)? Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/615930/edit) the question above with the new information.

Comment: @user68186 I've seen your comment, I need some time to check how to do that and to do it, I'll edit when it's done. Thanks

Comment: If your computer came with Windows 8 or above pre-installed, then you most likely have UEFI. If your computer was built before Windows 8 came out (2012) then it probably has the old style BIOS.

Comment: My comp hadn't any os pre-installed, however it is recent, I bought  it in 2014

Comment: Best to see lots of detail. Post link to Summary report. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info Do not run any autofix unless someone has reviewed details. You can install directly into your Ubuntu or into live installer.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I have never used EasyBCD; this answer is only based on EasyBCD documentation pages. Follow the links for further instructions.

You can choose to skip any of both bootloaders while keeping both of them installed. Since you mentioned you wanted to keep GRUB, the first option will be more relevant to you.

## Keep GRUB

1. Set Ubuntu/GRUB (or however EasyBCD calls it) as the default entry. (Source: [Changing the default boot entry](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/basics/changing-default-entry/))
2. Set "Skip the boot menu" as the timeout option. (Source: [Setting the Menu Timeout](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/basics/setting-menu-timeout/))

## Keep EasyBCD

1. Change `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` in `/etc/default/grub` using your favorite text editor. (Source: [Adding Ubuntu to Windows Bootloader](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/dual-boot/linux/ubuntu/#Adding_Ubuntu_to_the_Windows_Bootloader); see Step Six)

Note: it is assumed that Ubuntu is the first boot option in GRUB. If for some reason it is not, you can change `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` to another value in order to boot the correct option.

If you ever change your mind on the bootloader you want to keep, you can revert your changes and proceed to the other option.